# connection between Android and Postgresql via php

Tags: php, android, postgresql-9.1

i'm new in android application development. i have given a task to develop an android project that can connect to PostgreSQL via PHP which the database is not a localhost. can u guys help me on how to do the connection.

Comment: Show your code. We'll help you to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

There are various posts in SO relating to PHP integration with Android apps. You want to search for Android JSON. That's how I was able to link my app to a MySQL database on the web. PostqreSQL should be no different, except maybe the PHP query calls.

What you'll need to do is write a PHP program that connects to your PSQL database and runs a query on it. The query then needs to be formatted into a JSON array. My sample below connects to a mysql database. Since I have never used PostgreSQL, I am not sure what the PHP code to query it is. You should be able to find that info at PHP.net though.

```
<?php

 $db = mysql_connect('localhost','mydatabase', 'mypassword');
 mysql_select_db("myDB");

 $TABLE = isset($_POST["table"]) ? $_POST["table"] : "rep_table";
 $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " . $TABLE);
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $result[]=$row;
}

print(json_encode($result));

mysql_close();

?>
```

Your app would then make a call to this PHP file through a JSON interface, which you can then parse and get the values out of.

```
public class JSONHelper {

static ArrayList<NameValuePair> mArray = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
private static final String TAG = "JSONUpdater";

public String getJSONResult(String url) {

    String result = "";
    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        Log.d(TAG, "Client set");
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        Log.d(TAG, "Post set");

        if (!mArray.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "mArray is not empty!");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(mArray));
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "mArray is SO empty!!");
        }

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        Log.d(TAG, "response executed");
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.d("ScoreCard",e.toString());
    }

    //Retrieve the JSON data
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, line);
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("Scorecard", "Error converting result "+ e.toString());
        return result;
    }

    //Hopefully returning a string that can be converted to a JSON array...
    return result;

}
}
```

Don't want to overload you with info, because it can be overwhelming. Try this out as a starting point and see if you can get to where you need. If not, let me know. I'll try to help you out if I can.